# How to solve the setting change after using source ~ / .bash_profile in iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

When applying the source ~ / .bash_profile, the screen changes strangely.
Is there any way to solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O36tw.png)

Here is my bash_profile file.

```
  1 export CLICOLOR=1
  2
  3 export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
  4
  5 export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
  6
  7
  8 ##
  9 # Your previous /Users/leegm/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/leegm/.bash_profile.macp    orts-saved_2018-09-07_at_13:55:51
 10 ##
 11
 12 # MacPorts Installer addition on 2018-09-07_at_13:55:51: adding an appropriate PATH variable for     use with MacPorts.
 13 export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
 14 # Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
 15
 16
 17 # Setting PATH for Python 3.7
 18 # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
 19 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
 20 export PATH
 21
 22 export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/leegm/Desktop/smpl_/smpl
 23
 24 export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/leegm/Library/Android/sdk
 25 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
 26 export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
 27 export PATH=$PATH/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a shell other than `bash` and it's not interpreting line 5 correctly. You could just remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: yes!! it work! Thanks to you, I learned one more.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from line 5:

```
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

`PS1` is the environment variable used for the prompt text. For example, the PS1 from your `bashrc` encodes this format using green for `user@host`, and blue for the path:

```
root@computer:~/Desktop/$
```

Those escape sequences are recognized by `bash`, the standard Unix shell. I'm not familiar with iTerm2, but it looks like it's not reading the escape sequences correctly and is displaying them as plain text.

Since it looks like you already have a well-format prompt, you can just take that line out, thus leaving `PS1` untouched.